# Why does 逃げよ mean 'Escape!"?

Tags: renyōkei, imperatives, volitional-form

I have been watching some anime recently and I often hear people say にげよ (逃げよ in kanji maybe?) and it is usually translated as "(Let's) escape!".

I want to know why it is translated this way. According to my knowledge, 逃げ is the 連用形 of 逃げる, to escape. And よ is a sentence ending particle that adds little meaning to the sentence. IMO, "(Let's) escape!" should be something like 逃げろ. Does this mean that 連用形 can sometimes replace the imperative form? I have never heard anyone say 書き！ or 食べ！ to give commands.

Or did my ears not work properly and mistook the ろ as a よ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wasn't it 逃げよ**う** (with the last vowel elongated) that you actually heard?

Then that's what's called the [**volitional-form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Volitional_.28Presumptive.2C_Hortative.29) of a verb. You can create it by replacing the last る with よう for vowel-stem (aka ichidan or ru-) verbs, or by replacing the last u-vowel with the o-vowel equivalent and adding う for consonant-stem (aka godan or u-) verbs. Its primary meaning is "Let's ～" and "I'm going to ～".

- [What Does the "Volitional" Really Mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36505/5010)
- [Questions tagged with `volitional-form`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volitional-form)
- [Desire and Suggestions](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/desire.html)

The sentence-end particle よ (as in そうだよ, 楽しいよ) has nothing to do with the volitional-form. (It doesn't end with よ in the first place.)

---

In fact there is also 逃げよ (without the elongated vowel), which is the [**archaic imperative form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Japanese_language#Conjugation_table) of 逃げる (which was [逃ぐ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E9%80%83%E3%81%90) in classical Japanese, strictly speaking). The meaning is "(You must) escape!" This is much more rarer and never heard in today's ordinary conversations. But you may occasionally hear 逃げよ from a stereotyped pompous noble person, a ninja, a samurai, or a 1000-year-old demon in various fictional works.

---

**EDIT:** @kroki's comment reminded me that 逃げよう can be sometimes shortened to 逃げよ in very casual conversations. Casual/colloquial ("let's") 逃げよ is pronounced as にげよ{LHH}, whereas the archaic/pompous/literary 逃げよ is pronounced as にげよ{LHL} (like にげろ{LHL}).

Comment: Though rare, imperative form shouldn't be neglected, or you won't be able to appreciate [touching moments](http://livedoor.blogimg.jp/dark_eyes_illustnist-yugicolle/imgs/7/c/7cdba528.jpg) of life, your dog will [leave you](http://stamp.bokete.jp/10338366.png), and you'll end up reading books about [loneliness](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C4dYiu8VUAI0jOx.jpg).

Comment: @kroki 似げよ in the first two links is actually a variation of 逃げよう. Only the last one about loneliness is the archaic 逃げよ.

Comment: I'm not in the position to argue, but at least for the first picture I imagined a scene that the girl has already decided: she is going to run away.  So she tells a taller person: "come with me!" - and that looked like imperative to me.  Volitional would convey another story: the girl _wants_ to escape, but lets the taller person to have a final say.  Anyway, thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: @kroki She's inviting the person to run away with her, not ordering that person to run away.

Comment: @Nothingatall, yes, now I see it that way too, thanks.  Perhaps it's worth noting that you may use 命令形 for _requests_ as well as orders (一緒に逃げて下さい is in 命令形), so I can imagine 一緒に逃げろ (and by extension よ form) as a request as well (though perhaps not from a female, OTOH I know nothing about power dynamics of their relations, and hey, she could be that 1000-year-old demon, couldn't she? :)).

Answer (score 1):

In Japanese Grammar,We have a Volitional Pattern.  逃げます is a Group 2 Verb. So as a rule we conjugate as 逃げよう(add) よう means Let's Escape. Other Verb is 食べよう let's eat.

forms 
Group  1

買います －　買おう let's buy

Group 2

浴びよう let's take shower

Group 3

勉強しよう let's study

Try to Search Volitional Pattern

Comment: I think it's _imperative_ 逃げよ rather than _volitional_ 逃げよう.

Comment: What's the conjugation of Imperative using よ形 what I remember about Imperative is ろ

Comment: Please see last line of [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Imperative).  Both ろ and よ are used.

Comment: And also [here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%80%83%E3%81%92%E3%82%88).  So I think OP heard it right: 逃げよ is "Escape!" while 逃げよう would be "Let's escape..." (without exclamation).