# How is the volitional + と pair being used in the sentence "たとえ何が起ころうと私は主を信頼する"?

Tags: grammar, translation, volitional-form

In the praise and worship song [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zI2GcNhvovg&list=RDzI2GcNhvovg), there is the following setence:

> たとえ何が起ころうと私は主を信頼する

To me, this looks a lot like, "Whatever should happen, I will trust in the Lord."  But the volitional + と construction here, 起ころうと, is a little hard to get the exact meaning of.  I did check the answer on [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9688/1771), but am still having a slightly difficult time seeing why 起ころう was used, not 起こる or 起こるだろう.

It is also slightly difficult to tell for sure whether the construction involves the 信頼する phrase at the end, although the subject of the first is different from the topic of the second.

What is the exact meaning here?  Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48292/what-are-the-grammar-rules-behind-this-clause-%E6%89%8D%E8%83%BD%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C/48293

Answer (score 1):

The と construct also has a meaning of cause and effect, but it can also mean that despite something (in the part before と) happening then the consequence (the part after) will/could happen as if it were already a given or a matter of fact.

> その角を右に曲がると教会が見えてくる。 If you turn right at the corner, you'll see the church.

To be specific in your case,

> 誰に何言われようと俺の生き方を変えるつもりはない。 No matter what anybody says I won't change my way of life.

Comment: Thanks!  What is the volitional form communicating in this kind of sentence?

Comment: In a way, I could almost remember the volitional form being able to be used to mean something *might* or *will probably* happen, but was having trouble finding something to confirm this.  Most of the information about it just referred to it being used to make a suggestion.  I just saw this answer here though, which says that it can be used to communicate *might* or *probably will*, so I guess that's probably how it's being used here.  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/36506/1771

Comment: @Panzercrisis "Volitional-form" is not only for volition. This construction is [a pattern you can just memorize](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8-you-gayou-to/).